# SIMPLEINJECTOR & WPF Main windows it's created two times at startup when container it's verified

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, simple-injector

Hi i started a new WPF App and i want to use a simpleInjector as my IOC container.

I don't want to use at least for now any MVVM Framework but i try to implement all by my self.
I have a little problem (maybe it's WPF not configured corretly or i have registered not correctly the type).
When i start my application the container create a new MainWindow, during bootstrap, before the call to GetInstance method

This is my code:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private Container _container;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _container = Bootstrap();
        RunApplication(_container);
    }

    private Container Bootstrap()
    {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();

        // Register your types:


        // Register your windows and view models:

        container.Register<ViewModelFactory>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<INavigator, Navigator>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
        container.Register<MainWindow>();

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }

    private void RunApplication(Container container)
    {
        try
        {
            var mainWindow = container.GetInstance<MainWindow>();
            Run(mainWindow);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log the exception and exit
        }
    }
}

//ViewModelFactory
public class ViewModelFactory
{
    public ViewModelBase CreateViewModel(ViewType viewType)
    {
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case ViewType.Production:
                return new ProductionViewModel();
            case ViewType.Anagraphic:
                return new AnagraphicViewModel();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("The ViewType does not have a ViewModel.", "viewType");
        }
    }
}

public class Navigator : INavigator, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly ViewModelFactory _factory;
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    public Navigator(ViewModelFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand => new UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand(this, _factory);



    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigator _navigator;

    public MainWindowViewModel(INavigator navigator)
    {
        _navigator = navigator;
    }

    public INavigator Navigator => _navigator;


}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

What happen it's that when i call verify a complete graph it's resolved....there is a method to check registration vithout create a instance of all graph?
Do you have any idea?
There is something wrong on the registration?

Thanks in advance

ps. this is my first project with ioc and i want use them to understand how to develop in this way

Comment: The way Verify works is by creating all your instances. If this is not appropriate for your application, move the Verify call to a unit test. That way you still have the verification check, without the problems it causes during application startup.

Comment: Thk @Steven. i will make it!